# share point data source doesn't work using "Use as Windows credentials" SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, reporting-services, authentication, datasource

I have some reports and a data source on a share point. Everything is working correctly, but I need to change the account used on the data source. I gave permissions to this new account to login in SQL server. When I set the credentials of the new account, on the share point data source, it fails with this error "Log on failed. Ensure the user name and password are correct.", but if I log in using the new account directly in SQL Server it works correctly. I think the problem is only when I try to log in using the share point data source.

Regards and thanks!

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your data source

Comment: Hello @aliusman, sure! Thank you.

Comment: Did you make sure you adding domain name as well when entering username?

Comment: Yes @aliusman , I did something like this: domain\username.

Comment: OK, create a UDL file and test the connection to the database using same username and password - If you get connection failed then you need to look at the SQL side and it's not going to be SharePoint or SSRS, You can create a UDL file as per the following https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1409.how-to-create-a-sql-connection-string-for-an-application-udl-file.aspx

Comment: @aliusman thanks! I did the test with UDL file as you recommended and it failed again. Also, I tried using another account and it worked. What could be failing at the SQL side? Because when I log on, with that account, in SQL Server Management Studio it works.

Comment: @aliusman maybe you should know that it is a generic account.

Comment: @aliusman I did another test. I logged into the SQL Server machine and I created a UDL file and there it worked correctly.

Comment: No. Not on SQL Server Machine, Please create the UDL on the client machine and then connect - . Also, try to Connect from SharePoint/SSRS server using the same username and password.

Comment: I used a SQL login instead of Windows generic account and now it is working. Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem - I wish we could have fixed the issue with the Windows Login but SQL Login always works :) For me at least

Answer (score 0):

Check if the new account have the permission for SharePoint, if not, add the new user to SharePoint and set permissions for this user.

And I suggest you provide more information about the data source.

Comment: I tried, but it failed again. Also, I added a screenshot of the data source to the question. Thank you.

Comment: This account does not need to have access to SharePoint at all - That is a wrong suggestion